# can i modify my button onclick script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript code so when the user presses the button a clone of a div is created. The code worked fine however it didn't copy the div's properties, so if the original div has css properties the div clone wont have the properties. So is there a way to completely copy the div even the features it has.

```js
$(function() {
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('.note:first').clone().draggable().appendTo('body');
});


});
```

```css
.note {
width: 280px;
height: 100px;
padding-top: 40px;
margin-top: 60px;
margin-left: 35px;
word-break: break-word;
font-family: Note;
font-size: 30px;
background-image: url("images/stickynote.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
z-index: 1;
}

.note img{
position:relative;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}


.button {
position: fixed;
top: 160px;
margin-left: 44%;
border: 1px solid #000000;
background: #f2ad24;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffff92), to(#f2ad24));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92 0%, #f2ad24 100%);
padding: 13px 26px;
-webkit-border-radius: 16px;
-moz-border-radius: 16px;
border-radius: 16px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0;
color: #000000;
font-size: 35px;
font-family: Note;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.button:hover {
border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
background: #f08d24;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffe194), to(#f08d24));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194 0%, #f08d24 100%);
color: #212121;
}

.button:active {
text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
background: #f09424;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffe194), to(#f08d24));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194 0%, #f09424 100%);
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML
<div class="note" contenteditable="true">
<span id='close' contenteditable='false' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
    <img src="images/close.png" height="25" width="25" align="right" style="vertical-align: top; float: right"/>
</span>Keep clicking this text to select
</div>

<a href='#' class='button'>Create Note</a>
```

Comment: use `true` as argument for the `clone()`. Or if you don't want a deep copy, just set the class name on it from the original div.

Comment: Check this link : https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: @Mouser hmmm i tried this but when i move the clone the orignal moves and i cant move the copy

Comment: @Gusicindustry; that's because all the properties are copied. You must make it unique again. For example. If an element had an `id` the copied node will have the same id. Ids need to be unique, so you need to address to that.

Comment: You can also use $('.note:first')[0].outerHtml to get the full outer html and then create a new div based on that.

Comment: @Mouser so would i just set the .clone to equal a new id, in the javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the div, add it to DOM, and then make it draggable:

```
   var newobj = $('.note:first').clone();
// change the id, if needed        
//$(newobj).attr("id","newId");
        $("body").append(newobj);
        $(newobj).draggable();
```

Here is a jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bogtan8y/

Hope it helps

Comment: i tried the example but both my project and jsfiddle displays an alert that stops the button from creating a new div

Comment: It's just for debug propose in jsfiddle, you can remove in your code.

Answer (score 0):

use insertAfter jquery function

```
$(function() {
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var test = $('div.note:first').clone();
$(test).insertAfter("div.note:last");
});
});
```

Comment: I have test this and found all css properties are effecting regarding of classes also style tag is also being copied. Can you try this in separate html page. means remove all other code and try

Comment: I have included jquery 2.1.3 in your demo. after that is is working

Comment: check your jquery version and try to add latest if it will still not work on your end.

Comment: i added <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> to my html file, but nothing worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85312/discussion-between-farhan-and-gusic-industry).